# Inconsistent JFrame Size

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, layout-manager

My window component looks like cropped. The size when run and size in properties (minimumsize and preferredsize) is different. This happened both with Free Design or Absolute Design. I done these all with Netbeans 7.1.2. **What is the problem of this? Do you know what usual problem with this?** Is it bug of Matisse? I don't know what happen. **How do I can solve this?** I am sorry for mistakes. Thank you.

[image: Inconsistent Size - Illustrated]

I don't know where the error from the code but this is that frame's code:

```
jButton4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/otodidak/gambar/logomati.png"))); // NOI18N
jButton4.setToolTipText("Tutup Otodidak");
jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
setTitle("Otodidak");
setAlwaysOnTop(true);
setLocationByPlatform(true);
setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(787, 410));
setResizable(false);
getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
getContentPane().add(jSeparator1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(48, 53, 689, -1));

btBack.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/otodidak/gambar/backlogo2.png"))); // NOI18N
btBack.setToolTipText("Kembali");
btBack.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        btBackMouseClicked(evt);
    }
});
btBack.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        btBackActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
getContentPane().add(btBack, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(224, 340, 130, -1));

jButton5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/otodidak/gambar/logomati.png"))); // NOI18N
jButton5.setToolTipText("Tutup Otodidak");
jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
getContentPane().add(jButton5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(718, 358, 46, -1));

jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/otodidak/gambar/synapticwvdial.png"))); // NOI18N
getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(388, 65, 348, 264));

btNext.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/otodidak/gambar/nextlogo2.png"))); // NOI18N
btNext.setToolTipText("Lanjut");
btNext.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        btNextMouseClicked(evt);
    }
});
getContentPane().add(btNext, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(396, 340, 130, 48));

jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
jLabel10.setText("1");
getContentPane().add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(48, 68, 36, 40));

jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
jLabel2.setText("Instal Aplikasi wvdial");
getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(90, 80, -1, 24));
getContentPane().add(jSeparator2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 116, 216, 18));

jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
jLabel3.setText("1) Buka Synaptic.");
getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(56, 132, 368, 26));

jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
jLabel4.setText("3) Klik kanan wvdial, pilih mark for Installation. ");
getContentPane().add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(56, 207, 346, -1));

jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
jLabel5.setText("2) Ketik wvdial. ");
getContentPane().add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(56, 170, 346, -1));

jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
jLabel6.setText("4) Biarkan Synaptic menginstalkan wvdial. ");
getContentPane().add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(56, 244, 346, -1));

jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
jLabel7.setText("Catatan: internet harus menyala.");
getContentPane().add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(58, 292, 298, 22));

lbJudul.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
lbJudul.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(254, 254, 254));
lbJudul.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
lbJudul.setText("Cara Menginstal Smartfren AC682");
getContentPane().add(lbJudul, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(117, 12, 578, -1));

jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(1, 1, 1));
getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, -2, 788, 50));

pack();
```

Comment: I seriously don't understand what the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

Usually setPreferredSize should work with most layout managers. Your layout manager will use the preferred, as well as minimum and maximum sizes of components, and then using setSize and setLocation to position those components according to the layout's rules.

However if you try to position components in locations that are too big to fit the layout manager will automatically resize to fit that component and may not stick to the dimensions set in setPreferredSize.